# slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar unwanted dependency

Tags: java, maven, log4j, slf4j

I'm working in a multi module maven eap project. Previously it was implemented to use slf4j to use as logging framework. I changed it's logging configuration to use log4j2 as the underlying logging framework (still uses the slf4j). I referred to [this](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html) document when I do so. But when I build the project and deploy it in jboss I get the following error.

Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings, Found binding in `xxx/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0.2.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class` and `xxx/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class`

P.S: I never add the `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar` dependency to `pom.xml` or in any of sub modules. I have no idea how that dependency is copied in to the lib folder.

Any comments guys ?

Answer (score 0):

Well as it says it means you have indeed several slf4j bindings in your project.
You are right to deal with it now as it can become nasty and hide logs.

You should run

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

to see which of your modules adds the dependency to slf4j-log4j12-1.7.2.jar. It is probably that you have a transitive dependency to it.

You problem has in fact several solutions:

1. you can exclude slf4j-log4j explicitely
2. you can use the "provided" scope
3. you can use empty artifacts

I am referring to the following [FAQ](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL). It is about excluding commons-logging, but should be the same for you with slf4j-log4j.

When I ran into the same kind of problems, I found solution 2 to be the easiest to set and maintain. But solution 3 should work fine as well.